# failed to resolve: android.support.design:28.0.0-rc02

Tags: android-studio, android-support-design

I am using Android Studio 3.1.4. Since I would like to make a Tab Layout, I add the code `implmentation 'com.android.support design:28.0.0-rc02'`, which has the same version as `support.accompat` in build.gradle but error appears.

May I know whats going on? How can I solve the problem?

Thanks for helping.

**My code**
[image: x]

**Error message**
[image: x]

Comment: It is not in the google repository yet [Google Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/design?repo=google)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by just changing version of everything to 28.0.0-rc01.

Answer (score 3):

> com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02 should be replaced by Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01

I think there's no rc02 exist in Android Studio because every time you sync the project the 
error still occur.
After you replace the rc02 to rc01 the project will works fine.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
}
```

Comment: I looked around in Google's Maven repository. 28.0.0-rc02 is there, but for some reason the design component specifically is missing.

Comment: I agree that there are some loopholes in rc02. I guess we can wait for more updates on this version.

Answer (score 2):

**Edits**

**`design:28.0.0-rc02` is published now, simply add and re-build.**

---

**Before edits**

So all you can do for now is use the previous version for appcompat and wait until design library new version `28.0.0-rc02` release.

So for now use this :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'.
```

I don't know why... But they(sdk devs) behaving like Microsoft..

**"Ohh..It compiles, lets ship it".**

They just launch and don't care about bugs.. after updating to latest libs every time, first thing i get is..

**"Layout editor preview errors.".**

i hope it will be easy next time. :/

Answer (score 1):

Because it's simply not there. the latest version of design support is `28.0.0-rc01`

see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/design?repo=google

Edit: now it's available

Answer (score 0):

Today I updated my SDK and the same problem happened. for me by changing my these two library versions, the problem was solved:

=>build.gradle(Module:app):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

changed to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

Comment: I have this error with I do implement this 2 pack at the same time `    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`, If I remove design, it work fine